# Two minipages side-by-side

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage

I want one minipage with text, to be next to another minipage with two tikzpictures.

I have this code:

```
\subsection*{7. Bereken exact de lengte van lijnstuk $TP$.}
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.6\textwidth}
$BD = \sqrt{1^2+1^2}= \sqrt{2}$ \\ \\
In $\triangle BDT$ is $TD=\sqrt{2}$ en $BD = \sqrt{2}$. \\
Dus $BT=\sqrt{(\sqrt{2})^2+(\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{2+2}=2$. \\ \\
In $\triangle ADT$ is $AT=\sqrt{1^2+(\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{3}$.
\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ 
De oppervlakte van $\triangle ABT$ hiernaast is $\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot 1 \cdot \sqrt{3}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ \\
De oppervlakte kun je ook berekenen door: \\ $\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot BT \cdot AP = \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ \\ \\
$\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot AP = \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ \\ \\
$AP = \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ \\ \\
In $\triangle APT$ is $TP=\sqrt{(\sqrt{3})^2-(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3})^2}=1\frac{1}{2}$.
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[r t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\coordinate [label=above left:A] (A) at (0,0,4);
\coordinate [label=below right:B] (B) at (4,0,4);
\coordinate [label=above right:C] (C) at (4,0,0);
\coordinate [label=above left:D] (D) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate [label=above:T] (T) at (0,5,0);
\coordinate [label=above right:P] (P) at (3,2,3.5);

\draw[color=gray, style=dashed] (0,0) -- (4,0,0);
\draw[color=gray, style=dashed] (0,0) -- (0,5,0);
\draw[color=gray, style=dashed] (0,0) -- (0,0,4);
\draw (0,5,0) -- (0,0,4) -- (4,0,4) -- (0,5,0) -- (4,0,0) -- (4,0,4);
\draw (0,0,4) -- (3,2,3.5) -- (4,0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\coordinate [label=below left:A] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=left:$\sqrt{3}$] (X) at (0,2.5);
\coordinate [label=below:$1$] (X) at (1.5,0);
\coordinate [label=below right:B] (B) at (3,0);
\coordinate [label=below left:T] (T) at (0,5);
\coordinate [label=above left:$2$] (X) at (2.75,2.5);
\coordinate [label=above right:P] (P) at (2.16,1.43);

\draw (0,0) -- (0,5) -- (3,0) -- (0,0);
\draw (0,0) -- (2.16,1.43);
\draw (2.22,1.3) -- (2.13,1.24) -- (2.06,1.35);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
```

They somehow appear underneath each other.

Comment: Could you include the minimal preamble that turns your code into a MWE?

Comment: @Dox what is a MWE?

Comment: just don't make  a space or blank line betwen them

Comment: @touhami what do you mean?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times before

Comment: Note that the optional argument to `minipage` should contain `t`, `c` or `b`, so your `[l]` and `[r t]` doesn't do anything.